# pass word from php to python, use that to perform several commands and print several things

Tags: php, python, string, nltk

I am new to both PHP and Python. I have a word in PHP in the variable $word. I want to use it in a Python script and display it in my webpage/ PHP file.

The purpose of my programme is to take a user-chosen word from PHP, $word, search for it in a huge set of text files, and whenever that word occurs in those text files, to then print the file name of that file and the .concordance result of that word.

My Python script is as follows

```
import io, nltk, csv, os
from nltk.text import Text
from nltk import word_tokenize
from pathlib import Path

//Get variable $word from PHP and use it as variable y in Python. Then do the following commands        

path="C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3\\folder4\\"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith(".txt"): # Considering only .txt files
                x=os.path.join(root, filename) # Joining .txt file name to its path
                text1=io.open(x, encoding="utf-8-sig") # Opening each individual source file
                textContent1=text1.read() # Converting it into a string
                t=word_tokenize(textContent1)
                temp=Text(t)

                if y in t:
                    with open('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\folder1\\folder2\\p.txt', 'r', newline='', encoding="utf-8-sig") as extended_name:
                        name_reader=csv.reader(extended_name, delimiter='\t',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
                        for row in name_reader:
                            row_name=row[0]+('.txt')
                            if filename==(row_name):
                                row_value=row[1]+row[2]+row[3]+row[4]+row[5]+row[6]+row[7]    
                                print ('\'' + y + '\' word has been found in \'' + row_value + '\'')
                                temp.concordance(y)
```

How do I get the results of `temp.concordance(y)` from the Python file to the PHP file? Do both these files need to be in the same folder?

`temp.concordance(y)` is neither a string nor an array but something called a resource I guess.

Please help. I am a newbie.

Comment: Hi, I would suggest you to specialize in either PHP or Python, and not the 2 at the same time.

Comment: What is your goal to accomplish? You are trying to do weird stuff

Comment: @Ben I have updated my question to include the purpose of my programme

Comment: @ankabout Can I do what I want to do with just PHP?

Comment: What is the CSV for? NLTK seems over skilled for a pattern matching job: `found = re.match( r’\b\$word\b’, text1.read() )`

Comment: @DeeGee Yes I think that in most of the time you could, and so for using Python instead of PHP.

Comment: @emi I need the NLTK for the concordance functionality. The CSV contains more details about the files. So if $word (from PHP, which becomes 'y' in Python) is found in a set of text files, then that text file's name is searched for in the CSV. The CSV file then displays additional information about that file.

Comment: @ankabout I need the concordance functionality from Python NLTK

Comment: @DeeGee : I think I don't understand the purpose of your program. What is the difference to using plain `grep`, as in `grep -R '$word' root` ?

Comment: Also, using variable names with only one letter is a bad idea. It's still worst idea if you need help from others.